# Pass current_user.id to external javascript file

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm trying to get current_user.id from a flask application into an external javascript file. I have a working solution, but am worried it is not secure as I am displaying the user id openly in HTML. My current solution is below. Is there a way to do this without showing the user ID?

```
// estimate.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dashboard/js/estimate/estimate.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var current_user_id = "{{ current_user.id }}";
</script>

// estimate.js
var data = {
    user_id: current_user_id
}
```

Comment: Ajax the user ID, set it in an encrypted cookie...

Comment: So set up an API endpoint that simply returns a user id? I guess that would work.

Comment: Or set a cookie on the back end. Still available in the headers but so would calling the ajax or console.log(user_id) after the call

Answer (score 0):

if you need not print the id in code you can set cookie with python when return the response and access the cookie using JavaScript

#### full code example:

```
from flask import make_response

resp = make_response("""
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
alert(getCookie('mycookie'));
</script>
""")
resp.set_cookie('mycookie', 'I am cookie')
```